# Very confused about is/are in a phrase connected with "and"

Tags: grammar

```
Daytime accuracy of the best component model and each ensemble technique are presented.
```

I think that it should be "are" as daytime accuracy of "one thing" and "another thing" is plural. Then, I am confused there should be a comma before "and".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably the subject "daytime accuracy of the best component model and each ensemble technique" is from "daytime accuracy of the best component model and daytime accuracy of each ensemble technique" which is plural.  But this is already rather peculiar, I find, because when the shorter form is used, "accuracy" should have been changed to "accuracies", since it is now the head of a plural noun phrase.

A similar example would be abbreviating "the length of the red ribbon and the length of the blue ribbon" which can be shortened to "the lengths of the red and blue ribbons", where you have to use plural "lengths" and "ribbons" because two separate objects are being referred to.

Once the subject is made plural, then of course the verb has to be "are".